# What does convergence in the $L^2$ sense to a constant mean curvature surface imply?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, dg.differential-geometry

I have been thinking about the following question and have been unable to find any literature on the subject.

*Question:* Assume I have a sequence of **smooth, simply connected, compact** domains $\Omega_s \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $|\Omega_s|=1$ and

$\int_{\partial \Omega_s} (\kappa - \bar \kappa)^2 dS(y) \to 0$ as $s \to +\infty$,

where here $\kappa$ is the mean curvature of the surface $\partial \Omega_s$ and $\bar \kappa$ denotes the average mean curvature over $\partial \Omega_s$. I can prove that the limit is in fact a ball in the following **two** cases:

1. All of the sets $\Omega_s$ are convex.
   or
2. I assume the uniform bound $\limsup_{s \to +\infty} |\partial \Omega_s| + \int_{\partial \Omega_s} \kappa^2 dS < +\infty$.

I would however like to remove these restrictions since they seem quite artificial. I have been able to rule out the standard "pinching" counter examples of a long rod with capped ends, but am not sure if there could exist other pathologies. Any direction to results in this direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the question before by accident. 

Comment: When you say "two cases", do you mean you can prove the statement using each assumption alone or do you need both assumptions at the same time?

Comment: Each assumption alone, without one another.

Comment: Is the second assumption so unreasonable? You need to make sure the domain doesn't expand or shrink indefinitely, and these seem to be reasonable assumptions for making sure that doesn't happen. What would be a weaker assumption that you need?

Comment: I think finite perimiter and an $L^2$ curvature bound should follow from the convergence.

Comment: But what would prevent the domain from, say, expanding forever? For example, if you just take a sequence of expanding balls, the integral you wrote is not just converging to zero, it's identically zero but the domains are not converging. Or you could take a sequence of shrinking balls. You have to have at least some assumption that prevent this. One possibility is to fix the value of $\bar{\kappa}$.

Comment: I have a volume constraint.

Comment: but i realize i didn't say that. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to consult any of your professors? Some of them are known as experts on stuff like this and should be able to help you as much as anyone on MathOverflow.

Comment: It seems to me that if the dimension is high enough, the limit could be an arbitrarily long chain of balls. The necks that pinch off will have $L^2$ norm of mean curvature converging to zero.

Comment: @Deane 

What you are proposing seems to already occur for $d=3$. Basically let $D_t$ $t\in (0,1]$ be a family of Delaunay surfaces with $H=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that $D_1$ is the cylinder and as $t\to 0$ $D_t$ converges to a chain of spheres. It seems that for $t$ close to $0$ one could take an (appropriate) finite piece of $D_t$ cap off with spheres and smooth it out to get $D_t'$ so that the $L^2$ average of the mean curvature tended to zero as $t\to 0$.

Then again this satisfies condition $2$.

@Dorian: You sure your proof using condition 2) doesn't show the limit is a union of balls?